# JNA loadLibrary() method shows an error with arguments

Tags: java, jna

I want to set image as a desktop wallpaper using Java. I found a solution in the internet but it does not work. I can't understand what is wrong with it.

Here is what it says to me?
Can you help me?

[image]

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.UINT_PTR;
import com.sun.jna.win32.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class WallpaperSetter {

        public interface SPI extends StdCallLibrary {

            //from MSDN article
            long SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20;
            long SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
            long SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;

            //Here is the problem
            SPI INSTANCE = (SPI) Native.loadLibrary("user32", SPI.class, new HashMap<Object, Object>() {
                {
                    put(OPTION_TYPE_MAPPER, W32APITypeMapper.UNICODE);
                    put(OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, W32APIFunctionMapper.UNICODE);
                }
            });

            boolean SystemParametersInfo(
                    UINT_PTR uiAction,
                    UINT_PTR uiParam,
                    String pvParam,
                    UINT_PTR fWinIni
            );
        }

        public static void setWallpaper(String image_url) {
            String path = image_url;

            SPI.INSTANCE.SystemParametersInfo(
                    new UINT_PTR(SPI.SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER),
                    new UINT_PTR(0),
                    path,
                    new UINT_PTR(SPI.SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPI.SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE));

        }

}
```

Comment: Well, that error message says that the map parameter is expected to be a `Map<String, ?>` but you're providing a `Map<Object, Object>`.

Comment: Ok. I changed to  `Map<String, Object>` and now when I choose an image it sets orange color as an desktop image

Comment: Well, that seems to be another problem which I can't help solve because I don't really know the user32 library. I'd suspect your parameters are wrong so check those as well as the documentation. If you still got stuck, provide a [mcve] (code, the image you want to set and an image of what you get instead) in a new question since this one is about compilation problems.

Comment: Thank you. I managed it myself. It sets only pictures which are downloaded to your PC. I was trying to set a picture which does not exist on computer.

Comment: @Nikita Welcome to Stack Overflow.  To save time for those of us who want to help you, please use the answer section to answer your question to show how you solved it, so we don't have to read the comments thread to know this still isn't an active question!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. All is needed to change `Map<Object, Object>` to `Map<String, Object>`